# Apache Tomcat Error: Socket bind failed

Tags: windows, sockets, tomcat

When I run my Apache Tomcat server on Windows 8.1, the server returns:

```
java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730049] The requested address is not valid in its context.  
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:310)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:790)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:544)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:67)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:569)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:600)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:623)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
```

Here's my Connector in my server.xml as well:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
           address="192.168.0.1"/>
```

And my Engine:

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="192.168.0.1">
```

And my Host:

```
<Host name="192.168.0.1"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

I should also mention that my private and public IP addresses are available.

Comment: You dont need to set the "address" attribute in the "connector" element. Does this IP fit our network settings? Is it the IP of the server hosting Tomcat? Use "localhost" or a domain in the "defaultHost" attribute on "engine" element.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your config

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
           address="192.168.0.1"/>
```

And given error message

> Socket bind failed: [730049] The requested address is not valid in its
>   context.

It seems that Tomcat can't bind to IP configured address **192.168.0.1** as it is not assigned to any available interface.

Make sure that IP address is actually available by running

> ipconfig /all

on Windows

or

> ifconfig -a

on linux.

Answer (score 0):

Change The settings to following and you should be fine:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

N.B. If your ip is not 192.168.0.1 then the above config will not work and you will need to `ifconfig <devicename  e.g.eth0/wlan0> 192.168.0.1` for linux, or change ip address of windows machine accordingly vide: http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/display/istcontrib/Windows+8+-+Set+up+with+a+Static+IP+Address.

Answer (score 0):

192.168.0.1 is almost certainly not your Tomcat host's IP address but the IP address of a router. You can't bind to a non-local IP address. Most of the time you don't need to specify this attribute at all, when it will default to 0.0.0.0 which means 'any'. About the only time you need to specify it is if you want to set it to 127.0.0.1, for a Tomcat that is only supposed to be accessed from the localhost.